# Resources describing Somerset English

Tags: grammar, dialects, resources

Can anyone suggest any good resources describing the grammar of traditional Somerset English (not accented standard English)? The Wikipedia article for the [West Country dialects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_dialects) provides a good introduction, but I am looking for sources that go into greater depth regarding the grammatical differences between Somerset and standard English.

Comment: You'd do well to research Cornish as a language as that is heavily Celtic (probably from Wales and/or Ireland) influenced and being geographically close to Somerset would have had a big influence on Somerset dialect as well.

Comment: AFAIK We do not yet have an alternate SE for questions of this kind. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two books on [this Amazon UK page](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_11?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=somerset%20dialect&sprefix=somerset%20di,stripbooks,219) are popular guides to the Somerset dialect. The third is an academic account of English dialects by Peter Trudgill, a prominent linguist who has written on regional dialects and on socioliguistics. The index has an entry for Somerset, and there may be some pointers to more specific works in the Further Reading section.